# Wait until web browser has loaded first page Visual Basic Net

Tags: vb.net, web

I want to do a 2 step Source-Download-Process. So I have like

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.first-site.com")

'HERE code for downloading and saving the source code of the site into a variable
'Directly after having downloaded the source, open the second site and do the same

WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.first-site.com/sub-site")
'Download the Source code into one string variable
```

The problem is that my web browser will be loading two sites directly after each other very very quickly, not enabling me to download sources for both sites.

I tried everything, I googled "wait for browser to load one site" etc. and everything that has to do with while loops to see whether a browser has loaded a site it crashes my program.

What to do?

Comment: If you just want to download source code, you're probably better off with a [`HttpWebRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If so, would you mark it accordingly. If not, let me know and I'll try to help further.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the `DocumentCompleted` event, as documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx).

Within your event handler method, call `WebBrowser1.Navigate()` to navigate to the second URL. Check `e.Url` to see which URL is being completed so you don't end up in a loop.

From the documentation:

```
Private Sub PrintHelpPage()
  ' Create a WebBrowser instance. 
  Dim webBrowserForPrinting As New WebBrowser()

  ' Add an event handler that prints the document after it loads.
  AddHandler webBrowserForPrinting.DocumentCompleted, New _
      WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf PrintDocument)

  ' Set the Url property to load the document.
  webBrowserForPrinting.Url = New Uri("\\myshare\help.html")
End Sub

Private Sub PrintDocument(Sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
  Dim webBrowserForPrinting As WebBrowser = CType(sender, WebBrowser)

  ' Print the document now that it is fully loaded.
  webBrowserForPrinting.Print()
  MessageBox.Show("print")

  ' Dispose the WebBrowser now that the task is complete. 
  webBrowserForPrinting.Dispose()
End Sub
```